# How to get a value from 1-1 table related to current user

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

How do i get a value points from one-to-one table that related to current user on a website. In short how to get current_user_points like a current_user_id in this code

views.py

```
   current_user_points = userprofiles.points
   current_user_id = request.user.id
```

models.py

```
   class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    points = models.IntegerField(default=100)
    telegramID = models.CharField(max_length=9, blank=True)
```

Comment: The question is a bit hard to understand. Are you asking how to get points from userProfile using request.user?

Comment: yes, i need values from profileuser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use reversed relation. Assuming that it has related `UserProfile`:

```
user = User.objects.get(id=1)

user.userprofile.points
```

Comment: Better to use `get_object_or_404(User,id=1)` :)

Comment: @SunderamDubey sure, that's true, I just wanted to show quick example, because the second part is the important one :)